# How do I configure medit to display UTF-8?

Tags: locale, character-encoding, manjaro, medit

My environment is set to use UTF-8. I produce a file in UTF-8 encoding. It works correctly on the terminal.

For example:

```
$ echo ééé > test

$ cat test
```

[image: img UTF-8 encoding]

```
$ echo é | od -t x1
0000000 c3 a9 0a
0000003
```

But medit doesn't show it correctly:

[image: img UTF-8 encoding]

I am using Manjaro xfce 0.8.11 / x86_64 and my `locale.conf` is `LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8`.

When displaying other locales, such as Arabic or Chinese characters, I don't have this issue!

A similar issue from a user on the manjaro.fr forums : [Problème encodage UTF-8 NON valide](http://manjaro.fr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=5154)

Comment: The problem is with your `medit` application that seems to assume the file uses an iso8859-1 (or -15) encoding and not UTF-8. 0xc3 0xa9 is `é` in UTF-8 and `Ã©` in iso-8859-1 or iso-8859-15 (aka latin1 and latin9)

Comment: What makes you think the UTF-8 encoding is invalid? It looks like medit is the culprit here. To confirm, post the output of `echo é | od -t x1`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas
using "Mousepad" 

[screenshot Mousepad](http://img110.xooimage.com/files/8/3/d/capture-d-cran---...06-47-08-49452c3.png)

using "gedit" 

[screenshot Mousepad](http://img110.xooimage.com/files/7/e/a/capture-d-cran---...06-41-24-49452be.png)

and $ echo é | od -t x1 give me : 0000000 c3 a9 0a - 0000003

Comment: Which confirms what @Gilles and I said: that's valid UTF-8 but medit treats it as Latin1

Comment: I have submit a bug issue to "medit" home page https://sourceforge.net/p/mooedit/bugs/185/ Thank you for support and help.